Creepage and Clearance for Mains powered flyback
I'm designing a flyback power supply for medium LED (10 W) which powered from mains voltage (90-240 Vac).
I followed the rules regarding clearance and creepage DIN EN 60664-1 (VDE 0110-1) for my device such that:

Overvoltage Category 3
Pollution degree 2
And Isolation material group 3a

Which give me minimum 1.5 mm for clearance and 1 mm for creepage.
My questions:

How is it possible that minimum creepage is smaller than minimum clearance?
Do I need to keep this distance along the L and N lines only until the rectifier only. Or do I need to keep this distance even until my trafo pin?


Because there are 3 considerations that is on my mind:

According to the DIN EN 60664-1, the surge test of 2.5 kV is for only a brief of time. And I did place a filter after the rectifier stage. Shouldn't this ease the surge and I can use shorter distance for clearance and creepage. And even before this surge got to the trafo side, the MOV should have reacted and ease this 2.5 kV surge?

Because there is size restriction (as always) my trafo should be small in size (EP13 or EP10). There is no way I can get 1.5 mm from the edge of solder pads to the other. I don't plan to use coating or barrier, because its adding my cost.

I can’t even use through hole MOSFETs for my flyback (of course except for bending the middle pin), because again the distance between pads will not be enough for 1.5 mm. This is because the drain voltage is already (Vin + Vreflect) and if I consider the surge Vin will go to 2.5 kV.

Please enlighten me, and sorry for my bad English.

Are you sure about your results and is Trafo rated for this? I get For Overvoltage Category 3 and Pollution Degree 2, and Material Group 3a:  Results= 3mm air gap  , Creepage = 5mm . 1mm is wrong and would fail a 1kV pulse test when contaminated with humidity.

@D.A.S. Yes, as it is a custom trafo requested with those standards in mind. For the Creepage and Clearance I follow along at the standards as shown in DIN EN 60664-1 tables in the appendix F.1 F.2 and F.4 for 2.5 kV surge test. So Im pretty sure about that.

Are you reporting the gaps for normal or protective ground paths in both?  You could change your round via to rectangular to put in a 1.5mm air slot.

@D.A.S. I think its supposed to be protective. What I know is that Würth called it "reinforced" isolated, and it said to be capable to withstand 3kVac. I did change it to ellipse shape, however I am unsure about the minimum distance of the paste layer small axis to the hole itself, as it is not only limited from the fabrication house but also limited to the conductivity if im not mistaken.


gaps for HV test need to be air slots for future creepage.  Cost of future failures needs to be considered too.



Not everything is a PCB. You may only need 1 mm of spacing in air for instance. In your case, the maximum value determines the distance you need to guarantee. Remember to include production tolerances. I once had a product rejected from JET due to PCB manufacturer max tolerance put us just under the required distance.

After the fuse, mains doesn't end, but new rules apply. A simple catch-all would be to use the same rules up to your bridge rectifier. If your transformer has the pins too close, place a PCB cutout between them for more creepage.

Your MOSFET is toast at 2.5 kV anyway. You need MOVs or similar before your bridge rectifier to comply with surge and burst.




Thank you I will keep the tolerance in mind,
You mention "Up to my rectifier", does that mean after the rectifier stage, the 2.5 kV shouldn't be there as the MOV will trigger? and so I can somehow reduce the minimum distance? As you said, I can put cutouts between pins, however that only improve creepage and not clearance. One solution that I can think of is to reduce the solder paste pad to eliptical instead of round shape. However this will make the paste edge very near to the hole, and no fabrication can do it below 0.1mm.
I did put MOV between fuse and CMC.


@FrancisS 2. Opposite. Before the rectifier on AC side. Once you are on the DC side and after your fuse and MOV, your overvoltage category “disappears” and you only need functional isolation. 3. After the CMC! Your CMC provides useful impedance.

Okay I will stick to the rule of 1.5 mm before the rectifier (L to N) to avoid misshaps. However I read in some blogpost that people reduce the creepage clearance distance after the rectifier stage (HV to PGND in my case), do you think this a good practice? especially after the overvoltage category dissapears. Im not entirely sure to do this because my flyback is operating for PFC. And thus after the rectifier (HV to PGND) will be halfwave with 340ish Vpeak, and not DC.

Most designers are pressed for space, so if the rules are less after fuse and rectifier, people relax the spacing accordingly.

@FrancisS Also, PCB cutouts are free. Use them whenever you need more creepage.
